# Getting data from multiple port using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below is the js I'm using to capture data from two localhost's port (1000 and 2000):

```
  var group1;
  $.get( "http://localhost:2000/api/group1", function( data ) {
      group1 = data; 
  });
  var group2;
  $.get( "http://localhost:1000/api/group2", function( data ) {
      group2 = data;
  });
  var group3;
  $.get( "http://localhost:1000/api/group3", function( data ) {
      group3 = data; 
  });
  var group4
  $.get( "http://localhost:1000/api/group4", function( data ) {
      group4 = data;
  });

  function work()
  {
     //This function will process all the data.
  }
```

I found out that the data from the ports will reach me in different timing and will not reach simultaneously. What I want to know is, how do I make sure that all the data from the ports have reach me then only I can execute function `work()`?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [$.when()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) execute a callback after a series of promises are resolved

```js
var r1 = $.get("http://localhost:2000/api/group1");
var r2 = $.get("http://localhost:1000/api/group2");
var r3 = $.get("http://localhost:1000/api/group3");
var r4 = $.get("http://localhost:1000/api/group4");

$.when(r1, r2, r3, r4).done(function(a1, a2, a3, a4) {
  work(a1[0], a2[0], a3[0], a4[0]);

})

function work(group1, group2, group3, group4) {
  //This function will process all the data.
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But I don't understand the (a1, a2, a3, a4) and (a1[0], a1[1], a1[2], a1[3]). Why is it different?

Comment: @Coolguy since we are passing multiple promises to `when()` the pram set of each promise will be passed as an array to the then callback, since the `done()` callback of the ajax request gets 3 parameters and the first one is the data the first element in the array is the data for each request... there was an error in the code... fixed that also

Answer (score 0):

call the `work` function on all success events and check all variables as `if (group1 && group2 && group3 && group4)`.

```js
  var group1;
  $.get("http://localhost:2000/api/group1", function(data) {
    group1 = data;
    window.work();
  });

  var group2;
  $.get("http://localhost:1000/api/group2", function(data) {
    group2 = data;
    window.work();
  });

  var group3;
  $.get("http://localhost:1000/api/group3", function(data) {
    group3 = data;
    window.work();
  });

  var group4
  $.get("http://localhost:1000/api/group4", function(data) {
    group4 = data;
    window.work();
  });

  window.work = function() {
    if (group1 && group2 && group3 && group4) {
      //you code goes here.
    }
  }
```